GeoJSON is null error in a Leaflet + D3.js
I am developing a web page with Leaflet and D3.js that draws the distribution density contours of a bird species (Ciconia ciconia) with data from the Global Biodiversity Information Facility (GBIF).
I use the library d3.v4.min.js and d3-contour.v2.js with a geojson file with the following code:
L.svg().addTo(map);

var latLngToLayerPoint = function(xy) {
    var point = map.latLngToLayerPoint(new L.LatLng(xy[1], xy[0]));
    return point;
}

d3.json("data/ciconia.geojson", draw)

function draw(geojson) {
    var svg = d3.select("#map").select("svg");
    var pointLayer = svg.append("g");
    var aedLayer = svg.append("g");

    var point = pointLayer.selectAll("circle")
        .data(geojson.features)
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
        .style("opacity", 0.25)
        .attr("stroke", "BlueViolet")

    var svg = d3.create("svg");
    var contours = d3.contourDensity()
        .thresholds(152)
        .cellSize(2.00)
        .bandwidth(7.97)
        .x(function(d){ return d._x ;})
        .y(function(d){ return d._y ;})

    var aedContours = aedLayer
        .selectAll(".contours")
        .data(contours(geojson.features))
        .enter()
        .append("path")
        .attr("fill", function(d,i){return d3.interpolateCubehelix("purple", "orange")(i/72)})
        .attr("fill-opacity", 0.98)
        .attr("stroke-linejoin", "round")
        .attr("stroke-width", 0.45)
        .style("opacity", 0.39)
        .attr("stroke-width", (d, i) => i % 0.5 ? 0.04 : 0.55)
        .attr("d", d3.geoPath())        

    map.on("moveend", update);
    update();

    function update() {
        geojson.features.forEach(function(d){            
            var xy = latLngToLayerPoint(d.geometry.coordinates);
            d._x = xy.x;
            d._y = xy.y;        
        });
         
        point.data(geojson.features)
            .attr("cx", function(d){ return d._x })
            .attr("cy", function(d){ return d._y })
            .attr("r", 0.95)
            
        aedContours.data(contours(geojson.features))
            .attr("d", d3.geoPath())
    }     
}

This page was running perfectly well on an Apache web application server. But I had to change the computer and install XAMP 3.3.0 (on Windows 10 Pro) and the page stopped working, showing the following error when a try to open directly the html (file:///Y:/xampp/htdocs/SC/CONTOUR_CICONIA.html):

In the forum I read some posts proposing the solution of editing the XAMP .htaccess and http.conf configuration files, introducing the following code in the Optional CORS header for cross-domain origin access to all data:
 <IfModule mod_headers.c>
 Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin *
 Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"
 Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
 Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Origin, Authorization, Accept, Client-Security-Token, Accept-Encoding"
 </IfModule>

By introducing this modification the error message disappears when I invoke the web page with the url (http://srvmapes/SC/CONTOUR_CICONIA.html)

But another error persists related on GeoJSON file:
Uncaught TypeError: geojson is null
    draw http://srvmapes/SC/CONTOUR_CICONIA_2_2022.html:439
    o http://srvmapes/SC/js/d3.v4.min.js:2
    call http://srvmapes/SC/js/d3.v4.min.js:2
    e http://srvmapes/SC/js/d3.v4.min.js:2
    nu http://srvmapes/SC/js/d3.v4.min.js:2
    eu http://srvmapes/SC/js/d3.v4.min.js:2
    <anonymous> http://srvmapes/SC/CONTOUR_CICONIA.html:431

The GeoJSON file is the same without modifications.
What can I do to solve this problem?
Screenshot 1 network section of browser debugger:

Screenshot 2 network section of browser debugger:

Screenshot error message on doble click on geojson file:


What do you see in the network section of browser debugger? Any errors there?

The error, which I think is solved by editing the XAMP configuration files, says: "Request from another source blocked: same source policy prevents reading the remote resource in file:///Y:/xampp/htdocs/SC/data/ciconia.geojson (reason: the CORS request is not http)".
The second error that I don't know how to fix says: "Uncaught TypeError: geojson is null".

You didn't answer simple question: What do you see in the network section of browser debugger? Any errors there?

I'm sorry I didn't understand you correctly. I add a screenshot of the network section of browser debugger. In this section It seems to show the message "Uncaught TypeError: geojson is null".
I remain at your disposal if you need more information or further clarification.

Your error comes from the debugger console. Are you aware of Networks section in the browser debugger? Please look there what happens with the network traffic. I suspect web server does not find the GeoJSON file.

Thank you very much. I am not too familiar with the Firefox browser debugger, however, I am sending a screenshot of information I found in the network section that shows the geojson file. When I double click on this record I get this message "Fatal error: Unparenthesized a ? b : c ? d : e is not supported. Use either (a ? b : c) ? d : e or a ? b : (c ? d : e) in C:\xampp\htdocs\tileserver.php on line 210"

And what do you have in line 210 in C:\xampp\htdocs\tileserver.php file? Obviously server does not like it.

The content of line 210 is $s = empty($_SERVER["HTTPS"]) ? '' : ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") ? "s" : "";
I do not know, the installation of this component TileServer. I think it could be a previous residual installation that currently has no function.

I'm not familiar with PHP so I can't help you here, but it's obviously something wrong with the syntax. Diagnose clearly states that parentheses in the expression are missing, that it should be either (empty($_SERVER["HTTPS"]) ? '' : ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on")) ? "s" : "" or empty($_SERVER["HTTPS"]) ? '' : (($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") ? "s" : "").

Thank you for your help. I have taken the decision to delete all files related to tileserver.php since they are residual files from a previous installation and are not used on the server I am working with.
Now the web page loads but still does not draw the density visualitzation. The error given by the geojson file is Not Found. The requested URL was not found on this server.
I think the most effective thing to do is to delete the whole XAMP installation and reinstall Apache.
